# Redirect all url to a particular url same server domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I used a redirect functions in Cpanel though it doesn't work as I want it to.
This is the code from `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/about\-uspage" [R=301,L]`
```

`mywebsite.com` redirects to `mywebsite.com/about-uspage` fine.

But if anyone opens, for example, `mywebsite.com/any-other-link` then it doesn't re-direct to `mywebsite.com/about-uspage` which is what I want.

Note that `mywebsite.com` is a parked domain on my Cpanel and `mywebsite.com` is not my primary Cpanel domain name.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/about\-uspage" [R=301,L]`

Comment: that wild card redirect doesnt work.